# How to display on dual screens on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want my app to be displayed on both laptop screen and an external screen with two separated NSWindow, I can't find any document about how to implement it. Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: You don't really need to do much, as apps just work without any modification on multiple monitors and even with a single window spanning multiple monitors. What part are you confused about? Your question is very vague.

Comment: If you're asking about using multiple monitors in the fullscreen mode introduced in Lion, you can't. Panels can be placed on a secondary monitor, but proper windows can't.

Comment: @user1118321 I want to display the app on both of the screen. For example, I have a game and I want to display part of the image on one screen, and part of the image on the other screen. The two has different screen resolution. Is there anyway to achieve it?

Comment: @user57368 So for the full screen mode, one screen is most probably useless?

Comment: Yes. Lion's fullscreen API is worse than useless for multi-monitor setups. (One of the reasons why I downgraded to 10.6 when I found out that my mac wouldn't run 10.8). There are APIs that existed prior to 10.7 for creating full-screen windows that are suitable for things like fullscreen gaming. To my knowledge, they have not been deprecated (because they're still the right way to go for games), so use those and ignore the newer fullscreen mode.

Comment: @user57368 Any hints for the APIs? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [OS X OpenGL Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH210-SW4) shows the old way of making a full-screen window:

> 1. Create a screen-sized window on the display you want to take over:
>
>    ```
>    NSRect mainDisplayRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
>    NSWindow *fullScreenWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: mainDisplayRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
>        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
>    ```
> 2. Set the window level to be above the menu bar.:
>
>    ```
>    [fullScreenWindow setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
>    ```
> 3. Perform any other window configuration you desire:
>
>    ```
>    [fullScreenWindow setOpaque:YES];
>    [fullScreenWindow setHidesOnDeactivate:YES];
>    ```
> 4. Create a view with a double-buffered OpenGL context and attach it to the window:
>
>    ```
>    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attrs[] =
>    {
>        NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
>        0
>    };
>    NSOpenGLPixelFormat* pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attrs];
>
>    NSRect viewRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, mainDisplayRect.size.width, mainDisplayRect.size.height);
>    MyOpenGLView *fullScreenView = [[MyOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect pixelFormat: pixelFormat];
>    [fullScreenWindow setContentView: fullScreenView];
>    ```
> 5. Show the window:
>
>    ```
>    [fullScreenWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
>    ```

You can use this method to create windows on each screen that you want to draw to. If you use this to create a window on only one screen, the other screen will continue to function normally, instead of being blacked out or covered in a stupid linen texture. Depending on your use, you may not want to `setHidesOnDeactivate`.

There are also lower-level APIs to take control of a screen completely and prevent the OS or any other application from drawing to the screen, but their use is seldom justified.

EDIT: If you want to have one GL context with the render spanning multiple screens, you need to create a single window with a `NSRect` that spans all the screens. If the screen resolutions aren't matched, this may result in part of your window not being visible, and low-end graphics chips may have some problems.